# Parameter passed to controller is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, parameters, controller

When I'm trying to post the form, than is the parameter of the method in controller null. So what's wrong with the code?

**index.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Settings",  FormMethod.Post, new { id = "test1" }))
{
  <input type="submit" name="SaveButton" value="Save" />
}
```

**Settingscontroller-**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**FormExtensions.BeginForm Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, Object, FormMethod, Object)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460542%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Settings",  new { id = "test1" }, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
  <input type="submit" name="SaveButton" value="Save" />
}
```

You are using [FormExtensions.BeginForm Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, FormMethod, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), where object is for the HTML attributes to set for the element. Currently it is setting the id of the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source of your page...

new { id = "test1" } sets the id of the form tag. You need to set some sort of input tag within the curly braces of your form, like you did with the submit input.